# Heroku-18 gm convert: Unable to access configuration file (type.mgk) [No such file or directory]

Tags: heroku

When upgrading Node.js app from cedar-14 to Heroku-18, we saw this error in the log:

```
gm convert: Unable to access configuration file (type.mgk) [No such file or directory].
```

This is the Aptfile used:

```
graphicsmagick
libpng-dev
zlib1g-dev
libjasper-dev
libjasper1
```

The grahicsmagick version is:

```
GraphicsMagick 1.3.28 2018-01-20 Q16
```

We managed to reproduce the exact same error by running this command:

```
heroku run gm convert -list type
```

Which will also throw the same error "gm convert: Unable to access configuration file (type.mgk) [No such file or directory]."

What is the reason?

Comment: Have you tried deploying a new environment with heroku-18? GraphicsMagick needs the configuration file type.mgk which it cannot find. There is a tutorial on how to create a type.mgk file here: https://www.hexacosa.net/blog/detail/185/ however to create it on Heroku you'll need to do it through postdeploy https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-json-schema you will also need to install the Python buildpack.

Comment: @TinNguyen do you mean deploying a brand new environment will solve this easier?

Comment: It is definitely worth a try. It'd be bad if it only works on an upgraded environment since that would mean you are still having dependencies on Ubuntu 14.04 specific files and packages which are no longer available on a fresh Ubuntu 18.04. Also the Aptfile tells us you are using third party libraries and they may have incompatible files that block a successful upgrade. To rule this error out you should try deploying a new environment.

Comment: @TinNguyen thanks for the advise. will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

At the end, I solved the problem by switching to another buildpack:
https://github.com/bogini/heroku-buildpack-graphicsmagick

Including having these in Apt file:

```
debhelper
g++
gsfonts
libbz2-dev
libexif-dev
libfreetype6-dev
libice-dev
libjbig-dev
libjpeg-dev
liblcms2-dev
libltdl-dev
libpng-dev
libsm-dev
libtiff-dev
libwebp-dev
libwmf-dev
libx11-dev
libxext-dev
libxml2-dev
perl
sharutils
transfig
x11proto-core-dev
zlib1g-dev
```

After changing this buildpack and re-deploy, the error is gone.